# How can I use jupyter to edit a file on jupyter server, such as "~/.bashrc”

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to edit a file on Jupyter server,
add "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim" to "/.bashrc".
but I can't switch to bash terminal window.
If can I edit "/.bashrc" directly using Jupyter?
Thanks!

Comment: I have tried using "%%writefile  ~/.bashrc"
The %pycat command result showing
"...
*** ERROR: EOF in multi-line statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%%writefile myfile` to to save the content of the current cell into a file. Use `%less myfile`to show the file content:

```
In [1]: %%writefile myfile
        My file content

In [2]: %less myfile
```

You can load the file content with `%load myfile` into a cell first.

Comment: My environment is tensorflow on nvidia-docker. And I want run inception v4 on it. when I copy inception-v4.py code to my jupyter and run it, it is a error message:
 "ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-89d7d64fed75> in <module>()
     26 import tensorflow as tf
     27 
---> 28 from nets import inception_utils
     29 
     30 slim = tf.contrib.slim

ImportError: No module named nets"
So I searched for the solution, and got one from stackoverflow telling to add a path variable "PYTHONPATH". I think add path to PATH may also OK

Comment: Then I used "%%writefile ~/.bashrc" added a line "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim" to “~/.bashrc" file and exam using %pycat. At the end of the code list show a line "*** ERROR: EOF in multi-line statement". I don't know where is wrong, even after using "%%less ~/.bashrc" command.